# golang: using nested structs

Tags: arrays, struct, go

I have two structs:

```
type person struct {
    name string
    age  int
}

type class struct {
    students []person   
}
```

Lets say that in the main function, I create and populate two person variables and then I want to add them to a variable with class type. How can I do it?

I.e.

```
 s := person{name: "Sean", age: 50}
 t := person{name: "Nicola", age: 35}
```

how I can put s and t into:
 `lab:=class` ?

Comment: May I recommend the Go tour at http://tour.golang.org ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should achieve what you want:

```
lab := class{[]person{s, t}}
```

Test it [here](http://play.golang.org/p/o_4r4xo5tq).

Before you continue working on your project it's strongly recommended you read the following:

- http://tour.golang.org/  (As Volker pointed out before me in the comments)
- http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html  (After finishing the tour)